# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Unsupported aggregation type SpeedSeries_speed_avg Health connect

Tags: android, healthconnect

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported aggregation type SpeedSeries_speed_avg` Health connect

This exception seems to be related to an unsupported aggregation type for SpeedSeries_speed_avg. I have checked the documentation, but I couldn't find a clear solution to this problem.

Here are some additional details:

- Android Health Connect version: 1.1.0-alpha07
- Relevant code snippet or configuration related to the issue: [image: refer]
- Steps to reproduce the issue: When read the AssociatedSessionData with aggregateDataTypes **SpeedRecord.SPEED_AVG**,**SpeedRecord.SPEED_MAX**,**SpeedRecord.SPEED_MIN**

```
val exerciseSession = healthConnectClient.readRecord(ExerciseSessionRecord::class, uid)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can offer guidance on how to address this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug and [it's been already reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/327273591).
According to Android team:

> Speed aggregation is not currently supported in the most recent versions of Android 14